# Stop flashing of reloading iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I made a **PHP** page which reloads itself every few seconds with the `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">` tag. I included this page into another with the `<iframe>` tag.

The result of this is, that the iframe reloads itself as expected, but every time it shows a blank loading page for some miliseconds.

Is there any way to bypass or suppress this? (For example, using javascript?)

Comment: The best approach would be to not refresh that page, and instead do a partial reload or update its contents based on an AJAX call.

Comment: Yes, use ajax to get the contents and replace them when they are in. You'd probably need to get rid of the iframe.

Comment: @E.Reutlinger have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your content doesnt need to be inside of a iframe you can try this:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
    function load(){
        $('#container').load('yourContent.php',function () {
             $(this).unwrap();
        });
    }

    load(); // run it on pageload
    setInterval(function(){
        load() // this will run every 5 seconds
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already read about that way but it never worked for my. Somehow, it loads the page now, but the setInterval function seems not to work. Do you know if this is functioning on mobile too?

Comment: Sry, seems like a made a little fault there... it's fixed now.

Comment: No, still no reload. The `setInterval` function seems not to work for me

Comment: Could you please try the following fiddle and tell me if it works for you: https://jsfiddle.net/hhcehmp1/